# yq - issue adding yaml into yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, argocd, yq

Hi I would like to update a yaml like string into a yaml

i do have the following yaml file `argocd.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name:my-app
spec:
  project: xxx
  destination:
    server: xxx
    namespace: xxx
  source:
    repoURL: xxx
    targetRevision: dev
    path: yyy
    helm:
      values: |-
        image:
          tag: "mytag"
          repository: "myrepo-image"
          registry: "myregistry"
```

and ultimatively I want to replace the value of tag. Unfortunately this is a yaml in a yaml configuration.

My Idea so far was:

1. extract value into another values.yaml
2. Update the tag
3. evaluate the values in the argocd.yaml with the values.yaml
   So what worked is:

```
# get the yaml in the yaml and save as yaml
yq e .spec.source.helm.values argocd.yaml > helm_values.yaml
# replace the tag value
yq e '.image.tag=newtag' helm_values.yaml
```

and then I want to add the content of the `helm_values.yaml` file as string into the `argocd.yaml`
I tried it the following but I can't get it work

```
# idea 1
###################
yq eval 'select(fileIndex==0).spec.source.helm.values =  select(fileIndex==1) | select(fileIndex==0)' argocd.yaml values.yaml

# this does not update the values but add back slashes 

values: "\nimage:\n  tag: \"mytag\"\n  repository: \"myrepo-image\"\n  registry: \"myregistry\""

# idea 2
##################
yq eval '.spec.source.helm.values = "'"$(< values.yaml)"'"' argocd.yam

here i am not getting the quite escape correctly and it fails with

Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 2:9 failing at 2:12.
        unmatched text: "newtag"
```

Any Idea how to solve this or is there a better way to replace a value in such a file?
I am using yq from https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach can work, but in a roundabout way, as [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) does not support updating [multi-line block literals](http://yaml-multiline.info/) yet

One way to solve this, with the existing constructs would be to do below, without having to create a temporary YAML file

```
o="$(yq e '.spec.source.helm.values' yaml | yq e '.image.tag="footag"' -)" yq e -i '.spec.source.helm.values = strenv(o)' argocd.yaml
```

The solution above relies on [passing a user defined variable](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators) as a string, that can be used in the yq expression using `strenv()`. The value for the variable `o` is set by using [Command substitution $(..)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) feature in bash. Inside the substitution construct, we extract the block literal content as a YAML object and apply another filter to modify the tag as we need. So at the end of substitution, the value of `o` will be set to

```yaml
image:
  tag: "footag"
  repository: "myrepo-image"
  registry: "myregistry"
```

The obtained result above is now set to the value of `.spec.source.helm.values` directly which the inplace modification flag (`-i`) to apply the changes on the actual file

---

I have raised a feature request in the author's repo to provide a simpler way to do this [Support for updating YAML multi-line strings #974](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/974)

Comment: yes, now it is very clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update: you can now do this via the from_yaml/to_yaml operators, see [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode#update-a-multiline-encoded-yaml-string) for details.

```sh
yq e -i '.spec.source.helm.values |= (from_yaml | .tag = "cool" | to_yaml) argocd.yaml
```

Disclosure: I wrote yq

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fair point,  fixed